# NFC in background

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, nfc, intentfilter

my App already handles WIFI/Bluetooth connect/disconnect in background and performs background tasks based on those events.
Now I want to do the same thing with NFC but the all samples I've found so far are starting an activity when NFC tag is discovered.

I already tried to register a receiver for NDEF_DISCOVERED but it was not working...

```
 <receiver android:name="com.mxp.time.receivers.NfcReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Actually I already read that this is not possible because of the fallback stragegy of android.
The only solution I found so far is to define an activity without an UI and do polling on the connected tag.
I really don't like this technique because it would require to keep this activity open which would cause an increased battery use

Can anyone help me with this?

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that's not possible. NFC on Android was designed as a form of (intentional) user-interaction (and consequently uses user-visible activities). After all, that's what NFC tags are supposed to be used for.

Consequently, `android.nfc.action.*_DISCOVERED` intents are *only* sent to activities, they cannot be received though broadcast receivers. So the only possibility to receive them and make it seem to happen in the background is to use *an activity without a UI* that then forwards these events to your background tasks.

In case of the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent (with associated data), there is typically no need to keep the activity open to perform polling. Instead you could register the activity to be launched upon that specific intent. Btw. as Android is polling for tags anyways while the screen is on, there should not be much difference in battery usage when an activity is registered for receiving NFC events.

Comment: The problem is that my app is a time tracking software and one user put the request that he just wants to put the device on his NFC sticker to start tracking. 
I don't see the problem so far but he also want that time tracking is stopped when he removes the device from the sticker...
The only possible solution for that would be to keep the device awake and do polling all the time and that’s not nice :(

Comment: As Android (unless you apply some hacks to the Android system) only only activates the NFC reader/writer capabilities (and polls for tags) while the device is awake, the screen is turned on and the device is unlocked (there exist hacks to avoid that unlocked-restriction on rooted devices and there are exceptions to this on Android 5) there's pretty much nothing you could do about that.